# back button presentModalViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to have a back button when I go to another view controller but I have not been able to achieve this. I have tried to set the back button to not hidden with no luck. A little background information, there is no navigation controller being loaded when the app starts, I'am trying to go through one uiviewcontroller to another.

Here is how I have tried to achieve this, if anyone can tell what is wrong... it would be appreciated!

```
displayViewController *controller = [[displayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"displayViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *aNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

[self presentModalViewController:aNavController animated:YES];

[aNavController release];
[controller release];
```

Comment: You would typically add a cancel button in a _modal_ view and have it dismiss the view controller.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist What is the other day of doing it then? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put the back button in the viewController in which you want to have the back button

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 // back button 
 UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
 UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
 [backButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateHighlighted];

UIBarButtonItem* backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
[backButtonItem release];
[backButton release];
}

-(void) backAction:(id)sender
{
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: The OP is presenting modally so he would probably have to change `popViewControllerAnimated:` into `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`

Comment: he's trying to add a back button in the navigation controller i guess... which he's trying by presenting a modal view of the previous view.. if im not worng.. in that sense this code shud do the job of adding a back button

Comment: But the navigation controller will add the back button itself when more view controllers are pushed to it. The only place where it don't do that is for the root modal view that needs to be dismissed to "go back"...

Comment: i guess he's having a problem loading the navigation controller itself in the first place... I guess he shud be more clear of what he wants exactly.. check out the question which says ' A little background information, there is no navigation controller being loaded when the app starts, I'am trying to go through one uiviewcontroller to another.'